# What happens if the non-striker doesn't run but the batsman on strike does?

Tags: cricket

If the batsman on strike calls "yes" and runs to the non-striker's end, but the non-striker doesn't run, who would be run out if the wicket at the striker's end was broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the non-striker doesn't leave his crease, then the striker is out.

See clause 3 of [Law 38 - run out](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/)